# Why are seeds of summer chrysanthemum different between suppliers?

Tags: flowers, seeds

I bought some seed of [Chrysanthemum carinatum](https://www.pfaf.org/user/Plant.aspx?LatinName=Chrysanthemum%20carinatum) from two different producers, as seen on photos. How come they are different? The left hand side is 1gr, the right hand one 0.5gr. The price was about the same. Which one is better?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The ones on the left in the top picture look like Chrysanthemum carinatum seeds, not sure about the other ones, but just try rubbing one or two of the seeds on the left to see if there's a different appearance to any seed inside in comparison.

Comment: It is not so easy to crush left-hand side seeds into smaller units, but the result of rubbing and crushing is not like seeds on the right-hand side - there are no "stripes", and the shape doesn't look exactly the same. @Bamboo

Comment: I didn't think, when I grew these years ago, that the seeds were striped - not sure what they are, but perhaps they're a different variety of C. carinatum

Answer (score 1):

I bought a packet of "painted daisy" seeds that did not give the botanical name. The image on the packet, and the common name, most closely matched *[Tanacetum coccineum](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?taxonid=277669)*, formerly known as *Chrysanthemum coccineum*, and it has white, pink, or red rays and yellow center disks, [Painted Daisy (*Tanacetum coccineum*)](https://garden.org/plants/view/87040/Painted-Daisy-Tanacetum-coccineum/). Another name for it is "[Pyrethrum](http://www.theplantlist.org/tpl1.1/record/gcc-83879)". The seeds I have look similar to the ones on the right of your first image, though they do not have the prominent striping.

[image: Ferry Morse - Painted Daisy - Single Mixed Colors packet and seeds]

[image: Ferry Morse - Painted Daisy - Single Mixed Colors seeds]

*Chrysanthemum carinatum*, now known as *[Ismelia carinata](http://www.theplantlist.org/tpl1.1/record/gcc-128854)*, also came up for me when looking for "painted daisy" and those seeds match the flat round seeds on the left of your first image. The *Ismelia carinata* flowers look similar in form to *Tanacetum coccineum*, but the petals have a ring of color around the center, in addition to having yellow or orange rays unlike *Tanacetum coccineum*. The centers are dark brown to red [Painted Daisy (*Ismelia carinata*)](https://garden.org/plants/view/125185/Painted-Daisy-Ismelia-carinata/).

Given all the name changes of these two plants, and their similarity, I'm going to guess that your mystery seeds might be *Tanacetum coccineum*.

Comment: Good detailed answer, good illustration, and good close illustration; italicisation of text can be conveniently done by typing one underscore immediately before, & one underscore immediately after the text, or, by typing one asterisk immediately before, & one asterisk immediately after the text; We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!